# Windows 10 App - Combobox from JSON

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, combobox

So I try to create my first Windows App, and well its not going as expected..
Not even sure whats the best way to store the data either, at the moment I am using JSON but I could as well use YAML or even store these in the combobox directly

So I have a combobox :

```
  <TextBlock Text="Select Currency:" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbCurrency" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,15,0" Foreground="White" Background="#6649586D" BorderBrush="#660B121D" SelectionChanged="Currency_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Now I need to pass the data that is stored within my JSON file, which looks like:

```
"CAD": {
        "symbol": "CA$",
        "name": "Canada Dollar",
        "symbol_native": "$",
        "decimal_digits": 2,
        "rounding": 0,
        "code": "CAD",
        "name_plural": "Canadian Dollars"
    },
```

The combobox should take the "name" object within each property (CAD, USD, ...)
I Checked around but couldn't find some valid explanations in regards to JSON / YAML rather than DB's or locally stored in the Combobox. Would be glad if someone can help me populate this combobox using JSON values or tell me if there are better ways to achieve what I try ?

---

Ok Clint, thanks again, finally managed to make it work for a Windows 10 UWP based on your output it gives the below code which fixed the errors I mentioned in my comment "System.InvalidOperationException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll" and strangely, I had to rename my .json to .txt to make it work.

```
    public class Currency
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Symbol_Native { get; set; }
        public int Decimal_Digits { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    public async void ParseCurrencies()
    {
        string fileName = "Currencies.txt";
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/" + fileName));
        var json = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Currency>>(json);
        foreach (var keyValuePair in dict)
        {
            cbCurrency.ItemsSource = dict.Values;
            ///System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Currency: {0}", keyValuePair.Key);
            ///System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Name);
            ///System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tSymbol_Native: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Symbol_Native);
            ///System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tDecimal Digits: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Decimal_Digits);
            ///System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tCode: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Code);
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ParseCurrencies();
    }
```

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8fRn.png)

Comment: What is it you're trying to do **exactly**, as it stands your question is very unclear. Are you trying to read data and show it in the combobox? Are you trying to work out how to store the data?

Comment: Hey Thanks Clint, the initial problem is to get the JSON data within the combobox, so read the data and show it within the combobox (That's the main goal) - but the more I search on the subject the more I have doubts about storing it within a json file.

Comment: what data is it? How much is there? Is it just a list of currencies, or is there other data too?

Comment: Its a big list of Currencies - the JSON is actually on [Github](https://gist.github.com/hootlex/44ca79d763ee31efa0a2ee79ed14b43e)

Comment: The objects that are important to me are name - symbol_native - decimal_digits and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [NewtonSoft.Json's nuget libary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

The following code demonstrates the basics of getting the data out of the JSON:

```
class Currency
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol_Native { get; set; }
    public int Decimal_Digits { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\users\clint\desktop\common-currency.json");
    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Currency>>(json);
    foreach (var keyValuePair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Currency: {0}", keyValuePair.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("\tSymbol_Native: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Symbol_Native);
        Console.WriteLine("\tDecimal Digits: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Decimal_Digits);
        Console.WriteLine("\tCode: {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Code);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

What this does is reads the JSON as a dictionary, and JSON.NET is able to use the `Currency` class I made to infer the structure and pull out the data you want.

You can then bind the currency list to the combobox using standard XAML binding techniques.

For binding:

```
cbCurrency.ItemsSource = dict.Values;
```

=>

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCurrency">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol_Native, Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Decimal_Digits, Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code, Mode=OneWay}" />
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

^ That should demonstrate the basic structure you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Clint, so I went ahead and edited it a bit to try to create this binding but whatever I try the values returned doesn't populate the combobox:

`foreach (var keyValuePair in dict) { cbCurrency.ItemsSource = dict;}`

Where my combobox has: 

x:Name="cbCurrency" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Currency}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
SelectedValuePath="Name"

Comment: You nailed it Clint ! thank you. Also found out why it failed to read the JSON during my tries: 

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in app.exe

And looks like I was not the only one: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95394/unhandled-exception-when-using-newtonsoft-deserializer)